# Play small sound in loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I play now small sound with :

```
SystemSoundID reload = [GameFlow createSoundID:@"Reload.wav"];
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(loop);
```

Now i want to play this sound for 3 seconds for example in loop, there is any build in stuff for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything built in. You could play the sound on an infinite loop (i.e. set it to 99 repetitions or some appropriate number), then set an `NSTimer` to fire after 3 seconds and stop the sound.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html). Here is an [example](http://mobileorchard.com/easy-audio-playback-with-avaudioplayer/). To set a specific number of loops, use:

```
player.numberOfLoops = 3;
```